# Laravel select from JSON adding double quotes 2 times

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel this query:

```
DB::table('registries')->where('metas->name', $this->registry_name)->select(['metas->date'])->first();
```

Returning data like this:

```
{#1463 ▼
  +"`metas`->'$."date"'": ""2017-01-02""
}
```

Because of this problem (2x double quotes) there is problem with DataTables package, as result converted to JSON still have 4 double quotes.

If I remove `select(['metas->date'])` everything fine then...

Comment: Is column name `some->thing` i.e. with dash and greater than sign? If so, you need to put it into back ticks.

Comment: This will be fixed in Laravel 5.8. In Laravel 5.6, you can use the `->>` operator: `->select(['metas->>date'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

you need something like

```
DB::table('registries')->where('metas->name', $this->registry_name)->select(['metas'])->first()->date;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem we need to select column with inline path operator `->>` like this:

```
DB::table('registries')->where('metas->name', $this->registry_name)->select([DB::raw('metas->>"$.date" AS date')])->first();
```